# Underlying Container in View or Model in MVP

Tags: design, c++, mvp

Implementing a Finance app, and one of the questions that came up is where to keep an underlying container?  Right now I currently have these classes:

```
class DataGrid : public View { /* widget stuff */
class Presenter { /* handle DataGrid interaction and update model */ }

class Accountant : public Model
{ 
/* Model for entire application */
private:
    std::vector<Account*> mAccounts;  // QUESTION: HOW DO I KEEP THIS SYNCED IN DATAGRID?
};

class Account : public Model
{
private:
    std::vector<Transaction*> mTransactions;
}

class Transaction : public Model { /* Another model class */ };
```

My question is how do I keep the underlying containers in the models (Accountant, Accounts, Transactions) synced?  Do I have a container in DataGrid and in the Models?  Or do I just have the containers in the Models and somehow get a reference to them in the datagrid (view)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're asking how to keep UI in step with the model? Your model may change by other UI components, or internally, and you need all UI components to reflect the same model?

The [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is typically employed for this purpose. Each UI component is an observer of the model, and whenever the model changes all observers are notified so they can reflect the changes on the model. The presenter in MVP should be the one that holds a collection of observers and notifies the observers when the model changes.

For example, you may have an observer interface:

```
interface ObservesAccount {
    def onTransactionAdded(transaction: Transaction)
}
```

You would implement this interface in `DataGrid`:

```
override def onTransactionAdded(transaction: Transaction) =
    // add row to grid in correct location per transaction date
```

You would have a collection of `ObservesAccount` in `Presenter`

```
private accountObservers: Vector<ObservesAccount>
```

And any time a transaction is added, `Presenter` would iterate over `accountObservers` and invoke `onTransactionAdded()` on each.

Comment: The is correct.  The makes a ton of sense.  However, are you saying that each UI component has a reference to the model container?  Or just receives a notification that the model has changed?  What I'm getting at is how would a DataGrid display a model that is a loaded from a file?  It needs to know all the contents of the model to be able to display in a datagrid and in the correct order (by date in this case).

Comment: I added an example to my answer of how I would implement the pattern. Whether you pass the UI a reference, or some sort of copy of the data it needs is up to you. It's important that the UI *does not* change the reference without going through `Presenter` to do so.